# Trying to get a jQuery event to Fire onClick on a select/option form

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form, one of the fields is a select field, with 5 options. When the 5th option is clicked, I want a hidden div to be shown. I want nothing to happen with the other 4 are clicked.

It works on FireFox, but no where else. After researching it a little, it seems that Chrome/IE don't let you do the onClick firing with select. So far all suggestions have been to use onChange on the Select as a whole, but I haven't been able to figure it out to just fire the code when the 5th option is clicked using onChange. Any help would be appreciated.

Custom proptions is set to *display: none;* by default. I want the div id'd *custom_proptions* to show when the option id'd *custom_proptions_option* is clicked, and also want it to re-hide itself if it is shown first, and then one of the other options are clicked.

```
<div class="proptions_container">

<select name="proptions" id="proptions" class="proptions">
<option value="0" class="default_proptions" id="choose_prompt">Choose your Proptions&#8230;</option>
<option value="1" class="default_proptions">Yes <strong>or</strong> No</option>
<option value="2" class="default_proptions">Before <strong>or</strong> On/After</option>
<option value="3" class="default_proptions">More than <strong>or</strong> Less than</option>
<option value="4" class="default_proptions">Better <strong>or</strong> Worse</option>
<option value="5" id="custom_proptions_option">A <strong>or</strong> B (customize below)</option>
</select>

<div id="custom_proptions">

<input name="proption_1" type="text" class="text" id="proption_1" placeholder="First Proption" />

<span id="custom_or">or</span>

<input name="proption_2" type="text" class="text" id="proption_2" placeholder="Second Proption" />

</div>

<script>
$('option#custom_proptions_option').click(function() {
$('div#custom_proptions').slideDown('slow');
});
$('option.default_proptions').click(function() {
$('div#custom_proptions').slideUp('slow');
});
</script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do it in the change event, but only for the desired value:

```
<script>
    $('#proptions').change(function() {
        if ($(this).find(':selected').val() === '5') {
            $('div#custom_proptions').slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            $('div#custom_proptions').slideUp('slow');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, it's exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

The `clicked` is not the right event here. You should use `change`.When the event is fired, you check it's id/class(or better yet, the value in your case) and show the div if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 $("selector").live('click',function(){
});
```

I have much better luck with it.

Comment: also, there are plenty of live events.