# Ruby on rails with JQuery pass value from div to div

Tags: jquery, ruby

In a single html page, i have first div

```
<div>
    <select class="margin-bottom-20" id="event_title" name="event_title" style="width: 150px;">
        <option value="" selected><%= "Select a Title"%></option>            
        <% @all_events_title.each do |t| %>
            <option value="<%= t %>"><%= t %></option> 
        <% end %>             
    </select>
</div>
```

Second div,

```
<div>
    @events_all.each do |e|
        if e["title"] == **document.getElementById("event_title").value;**
            @all_events_by_title << e
        end 
    end
    <span><%=e["sport"]%></span>
</div>
```

how can i get the `event_title` value for second div dynamically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: something [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540541/trying-to-get-a-jquery-event-to-fire-onclick-on-a-select-option-form) may help you out

Comment: You want the second div to update when you change the value of the dropdown from the first div?

Comment: No, i want to pass the first div value to second div as a input.

Comment: The select dropdown doesn't have a value other than 'Select a Title' until the user changes the dropdown. The 'each' loop in the second div runs on the server well before. So, no, there isn't a way to do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script tag on the same html to add the div with javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    var $divEl = $("<div>");
    var eventTitle = document.getElementById("event_title").value;
    <% @events_all.each do |e| %>
      var title = <%= e["title"] %>;
      if (eventTitle = title) {
        // not sure what you are trying to do here...
        <% @all_events_by_title << e %>
      }
      var $spanEl = $("<span>").html(<%= e["sport"] %>);
      $divEl.append($spanEl);
    <% end %>
    $("body").append($divEl);
  });
</script>
```