# jQuery: Custom function for onclick event on select dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, select, onclick

Looking for a way to attach custom onlick event to a select dropdown. By clicking on either of the options a custom function should be called.

My code consists of the following HTML:

```
<select name="database" id="database">
    <option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option>MySQL database format</option>
    <option>PostgreSQL database format</option>
    <option>Oracle database format</option>
    <option>Other format</option>
</select>
```

Based on another question ([Trying to get a jQuery event to Fire onClick on a select/option form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540541/trying-to-get-a-jquery-event-to-fire-onclick-on-a-select-option-form)) I created this JS + jQuery + jQueryUI code:

```
$("#database").selectmenu();
$("#database").change(function() {
    alert("A1");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ba470wL/5/

There is something wrong and the function is not being called, where is the problem?

Comment: Your fiddle is broken because `selectmenu()` isn't a standard jQuery method, and you haven't included the library that contains it.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectmenu is not a function

Comment: Something still is not working there, even outside fiddle and with the correct jQuery UI library

Comment: Without an example of the problem we can't help. Remove the extraneous `selectmenu()` line and your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1ba470wL/4/

Comment: [Selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) is a standard UI component in jQuery UI and works in the same example outside fiddle, while the change event doesn't. I imported jQueryUI to the code example: https://jsfiddle.net/1ba470wL/

Comment: Try now, the problem with `selectmenu` is fixed in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to change the `change` event to `selectmenuchange`, which was caused by jQueryUI handling events differently.

```
$("#database").selectmenu();
$("#database").on("selectmenuchange",function() {
    alert("A1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#database").selectmenu();` is undefined

https://jsfiddle.net/1ba470wL/2/

Comment: Fixed it, but it was not part of the main problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve..

```
$("#database").on("click", function() {
    console.log("custom function");
});
```

You fiddle is broken since you're missing an external library (the one you're calling via `selectmenu()`)

Comment: I'm trying to detect the event when an option gets selected so another menu gets visible based on what option was selected.

Answer (score 0):

With the html from your example:

```
$("#database").on("change", function(){
//Code here
});
```

Comment: It may be useful to add an explanation of what the code does and why you've done it that way. It often makes it clearer to the questioner and in turn helps your answer get accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do.

```js
$("#database").on('change', function() {
 var selected_value = $(this).val();
    alert(selected_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="database" id="database">
    <option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value="mysql">MySQL database format</option>
    <option value="postgreSQL">PostgreSQL database format</option>
    <option value="oracle">Oracle database format</option>
    <option value="Other">Other format</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I need to capture the onclick event, which makes additional form fields visible.

Comment: Then you can get the value of the selected option and do what ever you need to do with it. See the updated snippet.